# Listener Service for list adapter

Tags: android, service

i am get data from google maps api, nearest places, 
how do I make a service that will listen when the place is changing , when new data coming, for i can use there a notification like "detected a new places" or etc. thx.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private static final String TAG = "tag";

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

ArrayList<String> listForAd = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, listForAd);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    List<String> filterType = new ArrayList<>();
    filterType.add(Integer.toString(Place.TYPE_CAFE));
    PlaceFilter filter = new PlaceFilter(false,filterType);





    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",

                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));

                listForAd.add(String.valueOf(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName()));




            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });


}
```

My empry service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {




@Override
public void onCreate() {



    super.onCreate();
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

checkout below, you just need to create a service and implements location listener

```
package app.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

class TrackerService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "TrackerService";

    private LocationManager manager;
    private ArrayList<Location> storedLocations;

    private boolean isTracking = false;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    storedLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Tracking Service Running...");
}

public void startTracking() {
    if(!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        return;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting Tracker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, this);

    isTracking = true;
}
public void stopTracking() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping Tracker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    manager.removeUpdates(this);
    isTracking = false;
}

public boolean isTracking() {
    return isTracking;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    manager.removeUpdates(this);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Tracking Service Stopped...");
}
public class TrackerBinder extends Binder {
    TrackerService getService() {
        return TrackerService.this;
    }
}

private final IBinder binder = new TrackerBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

public int getLocationsCount() {
    return storedLocations.size();
}

public ArrayList<Location> getLocations() {
    return storedLocations;
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("TrackerService", "Adding new location");
    storedLocations.add(location);
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
}
```

> 

```
public class Test extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button enableButton, disableButton;
TextView statusView;

TrackerService trackerService;
Intent serviceIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    enableButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enable);
    enableButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    disableButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.disable);
    disableButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    statusView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);

    serviceIntent = new Intent(this, TrackerService.class);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startService(serviceIntent);
    bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(!trackerService.isTracking()) {
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.enable:
        trackerService.startTracking();
        break;
    case R.id.disable:
        trackerService.stopTracking();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    updateStatus();
}

private void updateStatus() {
    if(trackerService.isTracking()) {
        statusView.setText(String.format("Tracking enabled.  %d locations logged.",trackerService.getLocationsCount()));
    } else {
        statusView.setText("Tracking not currently enabled.");
    }
}

private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        trackerService = ((TrackerService.TrackerBinder)service).getService();
        updateStatus();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        trackerService = null;
    }
};
}
```

Comment: where i must use your public class Test extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, in my Main Activity?

Comment: where i must write nitification? in onLocationChanged?

Comment: you can do that in any activity, where you want to initiate the service